# Serializing IList properties with .net core3 and the new JSON API

Tags: json, .net-core-3.0

.netcore 3.0 introcuced a new and fast json api. I have objects to serialize with list properties:

```
public class X {
   ...
   IList<Y> SomeListProperty = new List<Y>();
}
```

This seems not to work, list properties are just ignored. I tried to configure it with *MaxDepth* property, but it is not working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=netcore-3.0

```
services.AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth= 4);
```

It works with newtonsoft. Is this feature not supported yet?

Comment: No repro, nor did I expected it to fail - `IList<T>` is the interface implemented by both lists and arrays. Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Tnx. There is something wrong in my project. If I create a new one, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The new serializer from namesapce *System.Text.Json.Serialization* will not serialize fields that are lists. Newtonsoft serializer does. I forgot the setter and getter.
Wrong:

```
public class X {
   ...
   IList<Y> SomeListProperty = new List<Y>();
}
```

Right:

```
 public class X {
       ...
       IList<Y> SomeListProperty {get;set;} = new List<Y>();
    }
```